# Symfony 4 : setting {_locale} parameter in route definition leads to "no route found" error

Tags: symfony, routes, locale, symfony-4.4

I've a Symfony 4 app that is running fine until I want to define a route with the `_locale` parameter.

I define two routes for the same action with the following code :

```php
/**
 * @Route("/sites/{id}",
 *    name="site_get",
 *    methods={"GET"},
 *    requirements={"id": "\d+"},
 * )
 * @Route("/{_locale}/sites/{id}",
 *    name="site_get_with_locale",
 *    methods={"GET"},
 *    requirements={"id": "\d+"},
 * )
 */
```

When I call the url `/sites/1` I get the resource but if I call `/en/sites/1` I get a 404 error "route not found".

Here are the things I've tried :

- tried to change `/{_locale}/sites/{id}` with `/{locale}/sites/{id}` and the route is working but, obviously, the locale is not changed.
- tried to set requirements for the `_locale` parameter but it is no better
- tried to set the `{_locale}` parameter as a prefix (in annotations.yaml) with no luck neither
- I can see the route definition in the debug:router :

```
site_get.0                                      GET         ANY      ANY    /api/sites/{id}                                                 
site_get_with_locale.0                          GET         ANY      ANY    /api/{_locale}/sites/{id}
```

Edit 1 :
In the profiler for the given failed request `/en/sites/1` :

- the configuration sections shows me thet the Intl locale is fr.
- In the routing section I don't see the same at in the debug:router command : [image: Routing section in profilter]
  `{_locale}` is changed into `0` (even if I set requirement for the _locale to `fr|en`)

Edit 2 :
I was using Symfony 4.4.8 but downgrading to 4.4.7 seems to work.
I also have the problem with 4.4.10

Any idea of another path to explore?

Thank you,

Vincent

Comment: From a code perspective, everything should work. Actually it worked in my test env. Maybe you are lacking php-intl?

Comment: The app is running inside a docker container with PHP 7.3 with ICU compiled and intl enabled.
When going to the profiler page for the `/en/sites/1` request, in the configuration section it shows intl locale => fr. So I assume that php-intl is correctly set up